# Login works sometimes

Tags: module, login, j2store

## Here is a video of what I see:

https://youtu.be/Qbljr2CZu9k

## When I visit my login page here:

https://www.dev.plantbasedplanet.co.uk/sign-up

I cannot login using my credentials.

### However, when I fail to login I am redirected to here:

https://www.dev.plantbasedplanet.co.uk/sign-up?view=login

And I can login.  The difference seems to be whether it is a module or not.

Can anyone understand why that might be?

Comment: The links to the sign-up page do not work and give a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the video it seems that you have one page that displays the registration form and the login form displayed on one page. Is that correct?

The **registration form** seems to be a **component** which uses a `registration.register` task as hidden field in the form. The **login form** seems to be a **module** that probably uses a `user.login` task. When you display both on one page, maybe both different tasks clash with each other?

Do you use an IDE (like PHPStorm) in conjunction with XDebug? Could you see which task / controller is triggered?

Could you try using the same forms, but on different pages?

Comment: I have PHP storm but I don't think I have XDebug installed, so something new for me to learn.  I have migrated them to separate pages which solved the issue.  I still think that this should be a functionality that's possible, in fact I think it's very common that you either login or register.

Comment: I know that such a login or register functionality is common. And that it should be possible on a Joomla website. I've created such a functionality on a Joomla 3 website. It involved some template overrides. With an IDE + XDebug you can step through the code and see what goes wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing it would require a pull request to get it working properly.  Perhaps J4 has improved it.